Analysis Services table refresh progress
I'm using Invoke-ProcessTable to refresh a table in a Power BI Service and I would like to monitor what progress the job has made.  I can see the job running using the MDX "select * from $system.discover_Sessions where session_Status = 1" but I want to see what the refresh is currently doing.  If I process a table using SSMS the UI gives me a log of what the refresh is doing in the results pane.  Is it possible to get the same info using the session id or similar?
I've been trying to use the DMVs to get this information but must not be looking in the right place.  The batch response from the discover_Sessions DMV gives me a REFRESH object but doesn't tell me what object the refresh is working against.

Add the expected output.
